# Is there a way to optimize this code?

Tags: c++

I am working on this small piece of code, though it works as i expected, but i need it to be optimized. Please suggest me some ideas.

Here is important piece of my code:

```
std::replace_if(inputImage,inputImage+ m_xDim*m_yDim*m_zDim, bind2nd(std::less<float>(), 0), 0); // replace the values <0 with 0 of array input

std::replace_if(inputImage,inputImage+ m_xDim*m_yDim*m_zDim, bind2nd(std::greater<float>(), 4095), 4095);   // replace the values >4095 with 4095 of array input
```

As you can see i am make the value of inputImage to be with in the range [0,4095]. But, it is obvious that this is not efficient code, becoz i can have a loop running and do the both jobs in once shot. But, that becomes C style rather than C++.

Is there a way to use **replace_if** and get the both things done in one shot.

Comment: If you need to optimize, the "C++ look" is not an argument any more.

Comment: @moala: completely disagree. It's not because you need to optimize you need ugly raw iterator code. The C++ style is very likely to even get more optimized than you could ever do it yourself. It's just an issue of picking the right tool (as is shown well in the answers).

Comment: @KillianDS: there is not a tool for each task, sometimes you have to build your own task-dedicated tool.

Comment: @moala: yes, it can happen, but you should first look if a standard tool is available and if this is not the case switch over. You should not start with: 'if you need to optimize, drop sanity arguments and hack away'.

Answer (score 4):

```
float clip(float value) {
    return std::min(std::max(0, value), 4096);
}

int size = m_xDim * m_yDim * m_zDim;
std::transform(inputImage, inputImage + size, inputImage, clip);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `transform`, with an appropriate transformer, i.e.:

```
struct Clipper
{
    int operator()( int in ) const
    {
        return in < 0 ? 0 : 4096 < in ? 4095 : in;
    }
};
```

Comment: @KillianDS: you could have wrote it with if()s, but it may be more optimized than std::min(std::max(0, value), 4096) because the case in<0 does not trigger the second comparison. It only MAY, indeed, because the processing unit's branch prediction may interfere in the global task performance.

Comment: @moala: I wasn't actually complaining about the implementation, which is good imho, it was about the lack of ().

Comment: @KillianDS Looking at it here, I agree with you.  In production code, I'd write it in several lines, but that seemed to take up a lot of real estate for such a simple program here.  As it is, I did originally write it in several lines, then seeing how long it was, quickly joined them and posted it, without looking at the results.